# requirejs with jQuery .domready() is not fired correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, jquery-events, domready

When you load jquery 1.8.2 with requirejs 2.1.1 - `$(document).ready()` and  `$(window).load()` events starts to behave really weird.

Sometimes only one of them are fired sometimes both but in all cases they are fired after all content, images etc are loaded -`.load() event`.

Switching to jQuery 1.7.2 makes `.load()` work properly though `.ready()`  acts as `.load()` and is never fired on real DOM ready event. Am I doing something wrong here or not only me having these issues?

**Example** (open console and refresh):

http://jsbin.com/epujom/5

**Source**:

http://jsbin.com/epujom/5/edit

**EDIT:**
I have updated test case. Now it is clearly seen that `jQuery.isReady = false` even when DOM is ready

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how requirejs loads dependencies, but could it be that jQuery.js isn't done loading by the time your (really tiny) dom is done being parsed?

Comment: Wish everyone would provide such complete test cases on their questions. On topic, wouldn't it be possible that jQuery takes longer to load than your entire DOM (as you only have one image?) This way the ready handler is delayed until jQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i can achieve a result i wanted is to load **in the head section** domready plugin like

https://github.com/freelancephp/DOMReady

or

https://github.com/requirejs/domReady

domready plugin or attaching events should always be ran before actual browser domready event occurs otherwise all of them are waiting for all images to be loaded and that is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS provides a [lightweight domReady module](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#domReady) that you can use alongside other modules. By doing so you take away the need to wait for jQuery to be loaded and parsed before dom ready functionality becomes available.

More detail - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload